# How to manage non essential / derived data in Angular forms

Tags: angular, rest, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form where some inputs are derived from other inputs.  And I want to know how should I manage these purely informative fields within my component.

Here is an example:

Let's say, I have an order that contains a product id and an amount.

```
class Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

class Order {
  procut: Product;
  amount: number;
}
```

When a product is chosen I want to display its name and price. How should I manage this information?

I can try to synchronize the form with a local variable and update form accordingly

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <label>Product</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="productId">
  <input type="text" [value]="order.product.name" disabled>
  <input type="text" [value]="order.product.price" disabled>
  <label>Amount</label>
  <input type="number" formControlName="amount">
</form>

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
    'productId': [this.order.product.id],
    'amount': [this.order.amount],
  });
}
```

Or I can use something like this, where I bind all the data I want to the fields of the form.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <label>Product</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="productId">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" disabled>
  <input type="text" formControlName="price" disabled>
  <label>Amount</label>
  <input type="number" formControlName="amount">
</form>

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
    'productId': [this.order.product.id],
    'amount': [this.order.product.amount],
    'name': [this.order.product.name],
    'price': [this.order.price],
  });
}
```

Knowing that I'll be retrieving the data using REST and the data models can become more complex. How should I structure the forms and the models?

Or should I opt for a flatter model like so

```
class order {
  procutId: 'string';
  amount: number;
}
```

Then retrieve the rest of the data using REST calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with both options, however I would go with the second one since it makes the code more consistent, and makes your template cleaner and less dependent on the model structure.